# Does really convergence in distribution or in law implies convergence in PMF or PDF?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

[image]

Ref :Introduction to Mathematical Statistics-Prentice Hall (1994) by  Robert V. Hogg, Allen Craig.

Now , in the above problem it has been shown that a sequence converges to a random variable  X in distribution  but the  sequence of PMF doesn't converge to the PMF of X.

but we know that "a sequence {Xn} with PDF/PMF {fn} converges to a random variable X (with PMF/PDF 'f' ) in law or distribution if and only if fn → f ".

So, the example and the statement contradict each other . 
I think the logic that 'lim fn(x) = 0 for all values of x' because none of the Xn's assign any probability to the point '2'is actually wrong ! is it ? if not then what about the contradiction ?

Comment: "but we know that "a sequence {Xn} with PDF/PMF {fn} converges to a random variable X (with PMF/PDF 'f' ) in law or distribution if and only if fn → f "." Source?

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=IMbVyKoZRh8C&pg=PA256&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false


please see page 258-259 and page 262(theorem 6).

this book is published by Wiley and written by Rohatgi and Saleh.

 the same result i have found in many of my other text books too. and in general , while studying CLT I have seen many times  the books to write the PDF of standard normal instead of the CDF,when they talk about the convergence in distribution to standard normal.and i don't think all my text books have written it wrong as they've written it as a 'theorem' or a standard result.

Comment: sorry for being late. my internet is a little wonky

Comment: The page is not viewable. Anyway the "theorem" is wrong, as shown by the example of $X_n$ uniform on $$\bigcup_{k=1}^n((2k-1)/(2n),k/n).$$ Then $X_n\to X$ in distribution with $X$ uniform on $(0,1)$ but $f_n(x)\to1$ for **no value** of $x$. Let me suggest that you misread the statements that you "have found in many of (your) other text books too".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convergence in distribution means that $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ for all points $x$ *except* the points of discontinuity of $F$. Since the distribution $F$ for a PMF consists of a sequence of "jumps", or discontinuities at the points $x$ where $P(X=x)>0$, $F_n(x)$ need not converge to $F(x)$ at these points for convergence in distribution.

> but we know that "a sequence {Xn} with PDF/PMF {fn} converges to a
>   random variable X (with PMF/PDF 'f' ) in law or distribution if and
>   only if fn → f ".

Actually, this is not true. The quoted example is exactly saying that.

Comment: I got confused. You say "but we know that..." (quoted sentence) and after that you say that "Actually, this is not true".

Comment: Yes, the quoted sentence is from OP. I am saying that what (s)he claims (as quoted) is not true. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Ok, I read the OP's post, but I missed this sentence. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=IMbVyKoZRh8C&pg=PA256&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

please see page 258-259 and page 262(theorem 6). this book is published by Wiley and written by Rohatgi and Saleh. the same result i have found in many of my other text books too. and in general , while studying CLT I have seen many times the books to write the PDF of standard normal instead of the CDF,when they talk about the convergence in distribution to standard normal.and i don't think all my text books have written it wrong as they've written it as a 'theorem' or a standard result.

Comment: sorry for being late . my wonky internet connection :/

Comment: Theorem 1 in page 258 must be what you are referring to. That theorem restricts attention to integer-valued random variables, where indeed the stated result is true. However, this is not true for arbitrary random variables (not necessarily integer-valued), as in the example. I do not see how Theorem 6 is related, it has nothing to do with PDFs and PMFs as far as I can see. Finally, for CLT it is OK to state in terms of PDF, since Gaussian distribution is continuous and differentiable everywhere, hence the PDF has to converge at all points.

Comment: thank you. i think you're right...:)

Comment: you mean the theorem one is not applicable for all discrete random variables but only for the random variables taking integer values ?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly not true for arbitrary discrete random variables, but you can of course construct special cases (including strictly integer-valued random variables, as Theorem 1 does) where the PMF converges.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exact same example and following theorems in Rohtagi and Saleh [1] and was also utterly confused. Of course your "theorem" is false, as your example shows. The correct statements are the following:

1. A sequence $X_n$ of **integer valued RVs** with PMFs $f_n$ converges in distribution to an integer valued RV $X$ with PMF $f$ if and only if $f_n(x)$ converge pointwise to $f(x)$ **where $f$ is a PMF**.

The proof is a simple exercise. In your example $f_n\to f$ where $f$ is not a PMF, so the statement does not apply.

In the case of continuous RVs, only one direction holds:

2. If $X_n$ is a seqeunce of RVs with PDFs $f_n$, such that $f_n(x)$ converge pointwise to $f(x)$ for almost all $x$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to an RV $X$ with PDF $f$.

The proof is shown very nicely in [2]. The example by Did in the comments above shows that the converse is false.

Sources:

1. Rohatgi, Vijay K., and AK Md Ehsanes Saleh. An introduction to probability and statistics. John Wiley & Sons, 2015, pp. 287-288.
2. Scheffé, Henry. "A useful convergence theorem for probability distributions." The Annals of Mathematical Statistics 18.3 (1947): 434-438.