# Convergence in distribution does not mean PDF of $X_{n}$ converges to PDF of X

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to come up with a simple and concise example that demonstrates even though $X_{n} \overset{d}\to X$, the PDF of $X_{n}$ does not converge to the PDF of X. The research I've done so far has led me to the following two sources:

1. [Math Stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074284/does-really-convergence-in-distribution-or-in-law-implies-convergence-in-pmf-or)
2. [image]

The wording in the other math stackexchange post is just a bit strange. Is the example demonstrating how you can have the CDF's for $X_{n}$ converge to the CDF for X but the PDF's for $X_{n}$ don't converge to the PDF of X? It doesn't seem to ever talk about what the PDF converges to, which is why I'm confused.

Also, in the image, it looks like this is an example that does have convergence of the CDF but the PDF doesn't even exist as $n \to \infty$ is that correct?

Image from:
http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ayoung/m2s1/Convergencedistribution.PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples are demonstrating that it is possible for the CDFs of a sequence of variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ to converge to the CDF of a variable $X$, but the probability density/mass functions of $X_n$ don't converge to that of $X$. In example (1) the variables are discrete (in fact each one is a point mass). In example (2) the variables are continuous; the density functions don't converge pointwise, because the sequence 
of real numbers $$
y_n := 1-\cos(2n\pi x)
$$
for $x$ fixed doesn't have a limit except when $x=0$ or $x=1$.