# convergence of pdfs vs cdfs

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n$ be a continuous rv with cdf $F_n(x)$ and pdf $f_n(x)$. Let $X$ be a continuous rv with cdf $F(x)$ and pdf $f(x)$. It is known that convergence in distribution, i.e., $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ at every continuity point $x$ of $F(x)$, does not generally imply that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074284/does-really-convergence-in-distribution-or-in-law-implies-convergence-in-pmf-or?noredirect=1&lq=1) offers a counterexample. My question is: Is there a class of continuous rvs for which $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ does imply $f_n(x)\to f(x)$? What additional conditions are these rvs to satisfy? Incidentally, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074284/does-really-convergence-in-distribution-or-in-law-implies-convergence-in-pmf-or), pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $f(x)$ is enough to have $F_n(x)\to F(x)$.

I'm particularly interested in the case when $f_n(x)$ is supported on $[0,n]$ while $f(x)$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$. To boot, $f_n(x)$ is infinitely differentiable at every $x\in[0,n]$ for each $n$, and $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable at every $x\ge0$. In fact, in my specific case, $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $x\ge0$.

Comment: On a $\sigma$-finite measure space you have: $g_n\to g$ in L^1 if and only if $g_n\to g$ locally in measure and $\int |g_n| \to \int |g|$. Now remember that $f_n\ge 0$ and $F_n$ is the integral of $f_n$.